# How to read OS environment variables with Vue 2.7

Tags: vue.js, environment-variables

I have in on my OS defined an environment variable like so:

[image]

Now, I want to read the values of the variables in my Vue app.

In my .env file I have:

```
VUE_APP_GATEWAY_ADDRESS=localhost:8083
VUE_APP_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO=gwatt
```

and when I do:

```
console.log("Test two: " + process.env.VUE_APP_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO);
```

I get `gwatt` instead of `env GAT` (as defined in the environment variables).

Answer (score 0):

The os envrionment variable is `GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO`
You should try this

```
console.log("Test two: " + process.env.GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO);
```

As vue-cli docs says
https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/mode-and-env.html#environment-variables

> Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin. It is to avoid accidentally exposing a private key on the machine that could have the same name.

They use `dotenv` to load environment variables from .env
https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Comment: Tried that... that is then undefined :(

Comment: could you please open a new terminal and run `echo "$GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO"` to ensure envrionment variable is set

Comment: Yes, the variable is set to "env GAT"

Comment: **Note that only NODE_ENV, BASE_URL, and variables that start with VUE_APP_ will be statically embedded into the client bundle with webpack.DefinePlugin**  you may need to rename os environment variable to `VUE_APP_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO` to align with this rule. and then `console.log("Test two: " + process.env.VUE_APP_GATEWAY_ADDRESS_TEST_TWO);`